# Cancel AsyncTask when Activity onPause()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, thread-safety

I start an AsyncTask inside the activity.. The task request from server check if user info is validated. This task will run forever unless server returns user_validated or it's manually cancelled.

Here's the doInBackground() code:

```
    @Override
    protected ApiResult doInBackground(Context... objects) {
        AccountState accountState = AccountState.getInstance();
        ApiResult result = null;
        boolean isEmailValidated = false;

        while (!isEmailValidated) {
            if (isCancelled()) break;

            result = new MyApi().emailValidated(accountState.getAccessToken());

            if (result != null) {
                MyApi.EmailValidatedResult emailValidatedResult =
                        MyApi.parseEmailValidatedResult(result.getResponse());
                if (emailValidatedResult != null && emailValidatedResult.getValidated()) {
                    isEmailValidated = true;

                } else {
                    // token is not valid, sleep for RETRY_DELAY and try again
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(RETRY_DELAY);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        MyLogger.e(e, "Sleep between retry attempts threw InterruptedException!");
                    }
                }

            } else {
                MyLogger.d("email_validated returned null");
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Since this task will keep retry, I want it to run only when Activity is visible. So I tried to cancel the task when Activity onPause():

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mCurrentTask != null) {
        mCurrentTask.cancel(true);
        mCurrentTask = null;
    }
}
```

The problem is.. if `mCurrentTask.cencel(true)` is called while `Thread.sleep()` is being executed.. it will cause `InterruptedException`.. I don't know if that is ok. and how to handle it nicely without throwing exception.

Comment: The whole point of the `mayInterruptIfRunning` param is that it interrupts the background `Thread` of the task from any I/O operation or wait method by throwing an `InterruptedException` which you can handle to exit from it. If you don't want this, then simply pass `false` to the `cancel()` method instead of `true`.

Comment: an example for cancelling an asynctask http://www.quicktips.in/correct-way-to-cancel-an-asynctask-in-android/